# Table body column not same width as the Header column

Tags: html, css

Hello i'm currently creating a table,The first header have a smaller text content than the other Header while its corresponding Column on the Body have wider/bigger content since its a name of a group. What i want to achieve is that the column's on the header and content should have corresponding width depending on which of them is wider.

Here is the fiddle of the table: https://jsfiddle.net/pynechan/b4s3brqc/19/

```
//HTML
    <h2>Header fixed</h2>
<br/>
<br/>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>HEADER</th>
            <th>HEADER 2</th>
            <th>HEADER 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>1. DATA</td>
            <td>1. DATA 2</td>
            <td>1. DATA 3</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

//CSS


   table {
    max-width:980px;
    table-layout:fixed;
    margin:auto;
}
th, td {
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
thead, tfoot {
    background:#f9f9f9;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    width:calc(100% - 18px);
}
tbody {
    height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

tbody{
  scrollbar-face-color: ThreeDFace !important;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: ThreeDDarkShadow !important;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: ThreeDHighlight !important;
  scrollbar-track-color: Scrollbar !important;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: ButtonText !important;
}
```

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/b4s3brqc/21/

Comment: As per your fiddle link you want the table header to be fixed and columns should scroll, which is not possible via css right now. you need to use datatable js plugin to achieve this.

Comment: @PiyushVerma yes the header should be fixed :(

Comment: try [this](https://datatables.net/) it will solve your problem unfortunately there is no solution with only css right now.

Answer (score 3):

just add this script in your css

```
th {width:1px;}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. Where's the button to upvote this ten times?

Answer (score 1):

Please use below css . And It's work for me.

```
table {
    max-width:980px;
    table-layout:fixed;
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
}
th, td {
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
thead, tfoot {
    background:#f9f9f9;    
    width:100%;    
}
tbody {
    height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;    
    width:100%;
}
tbody tr {    
    width:100%;    
}

tbody{
  scrollbar-face-color: ThreeDFace !important;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: ThreeDDarkShadow !important;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: ThreeDHighlight !important;
  scrollbar-track-color: Scrollbar !important;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: ButtonText !important;
}
```

Comment: This align the columns but it will affect the header and will be hidden when you scroll up :(

Answer (score -2):

Better use Bootstrap which aligns the table header and body properly